# Question Concerning making a Test class for a before update trigger that sends an email

Tags: unit-test, email, code-coverage, before-trigger

I'm currently trying to make a test for an apex trigger that sends an email if a certain donation field has been changed(before this I tried using a workflow but for some reason it did not work). From what  I can tell the code works fine with 0 failures, what I am having issues with is creating the test class for this trigger. At the moment it is reporting a success but it has a 0% code coverage for this trigger. I'm trying to get it covered enough so that it can run in production.The test also runs without any failures and even has code coverage 
 for other classes that it wasn't made for.I have also looked at the trailhead tutorial and from what I can tell this class is following all the guidelines or at the very least  some of them to get the coverage up to more than just 0%. Any help with this or suggestions on a different way to accomplish this task?

Here is the trigger:

```
trigger Organization_Match on Contact (before update)
{

    for(Contact con: Trigger.new)
    {
        Decimal Donation;
        Messaging.reserveSingleEmailCapacity(2);

       Contact Oldcon = Trigger.oldMap.get(con.Id); 

        if(Oldcon.npo02__LastOppAmount__c != con.npo02__LastOppAmount__c  && oldcon.Con_Org_Match__c == true && con.npo02__LastOppAmount__c != null && con.npo02__LastOppAmount__c != 0.00 )
        {


            Donation = con.npo02__LastOppAmount__c ;
            System.debug('Donation was Made, Amount: '+ Donation);
           con.Description = 'Donation was Made, Amount: '+ Donation;

           Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            String[] toAddress = new String[] {'email address here'};
            mail.setToAddresses(toAddress);
            mail.setReplyTo('email address here');
            mail.setSubject('Donation Test ');
            mail.setBccSender(false);
            mail.setSenderDisplayName('Email Tester');
            mail.setPlainTextBody('A donation has been made or edited, please  make sure to review the information sent  and to check the contact and account to verify if this is a correction or a new addition, Amount: $'+
                                  Donation+ ' Contacts Last Name: ' +con.LastName + 'Organization: '+con.AccountNamer__c);
            mail.setHtmlBody('<p> Donation was Made, Amount:</p> $'+ Donation+ ' <p>Contacts Last Name: </p>' +con.LastName + '<p>Organization: </p>'+con.AccountNamer__c);
            Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });

        }


        else
        {
            System.debug('No donation was made');
            con.Description = 'No donation was made'; 
        }



    }



}
```

And here is the test so far:

```
@isTest
private class Test_Organization_Match {

    @isTest static void TestEmailPositive() {
        Account acct = new Account(Name='Test Account', OrgMatch__c= True);

        insert acct;

        Contact con = new Contact (LastName = 'Example',AccountId= acct.Id,npo02__LastOppAmount__c= 25.00);

        insert con;


        con.npo02__LastOppAmount__c= 27.00;
        Update con;


    }


}
```

Comment: Pro tip: testmethods without asserts aren't really proving anything beyond the code doesn't blow up

Answer (score 0):

**Summary**: This seems like a simple criteria (only when a certain field changes), a simple template to create, and something workflow is perfect for (do this one action when this happens).

For the criteria, you can use the ISCHANGED() formula when you select "every time a record is created or edited".

[image]

If, even if you use workflow for this situation, you're just interested in learning more about apex and why this isn't working here's some tips:

*You shouldn't be doing everything in the trigger*. Use the trigger to gather the records and pass it on to another class. If you ever need to add a new situation on this object, you'll always have to test this email process because you'd be messing around it. Divide your functionality into separate classes and methods. Also, make sure your names makes sense. You're naming the trigger on the Contact object specifically for this one business process. What happens when users want you to do something else on Contact? For example,

```
trigger ContactTrigger on Contact (before update)
{
    ContactTriggerHandler contactHandler = new ContactTriggerHandler();
    List<Contact> contactsToUpdate = new List<Contact>();
    if(trigger.isBefore){
        if(trigger.isUpdate(){
            for(Contact con : Trigger.new){
                Contact oldContact = Trigger.oldMap.get(con.Id);
                if(con.npo02__LastOppAmount__c != oldContact.npo02__LastOppAmount__c){
                    contactsToUpdate.add(con);
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
    if(contactToUpdate.size() > 0){
        contactHandler.organizationMatch(contactToUpdate);
    }

}
```

What this does is move all your email sending logic to its own method within a separate class. Makes it easy to test in discrete, separate functionality (you can test just passing a list of contacts and skip the trigger as well).

In your test class, even if you don't need to reset governor limits - use Test.startTest() and Test.stopTest(). It'll help you see where the actual work is going on. In your case, I'd throw a startTest() after the "insert con;" and then a stopTest(); after the "update con".

In terms of coverage, where are you seeing your coverage? It might be worthwhile to put some debug statements and see where it's getting caught up.

Comment: for my workflow  i definitely used the ischanged function and set it  the evaluation criteria to be the same thing. the problem that i had was that it was not sending any emails even though i had an email alert attached to it. i made sure my email settings in sandbox where open, but it still wouldn't send even though the criteria was met. the only thing that was able to  send an email was my apex trigger. also concerning my test yes it does insert a contact but that's so it can update it. what is the correct way to go about this?

Comment: My mistake, I missed your update statement after the insert. Again, I'd seriously consider looking back at that workflow as I think that'd be preferred over code for this process. Are you in a sandbox? Did you have the email alert send to your user? Is your email up-to-date in the sandbox?

Comment: Yes i am in sandbox and I have the email alert to set to be sent to one of my co workers. should it only be sent to the user? and for revisiting the workflow, is there anything that blocks them from sending emails  in sandbox ?

Comment: Check "Setup" (gear icon) --> Deliverability" --> Make sure "Access Level" is set to "All Email".

Comment: Likewise, are you adding a specific email to the email alert or selecting a user? If you're selecting a user, check that the user's email is valid and doesn't have ".invalid" added to it from the sandbox refresh process.

Comment: Last thing, check that you "activated" the workflow rule.